# Search in a 1D array A for non-zero entries and create a number of array B_k in fortran?

Tags: arrays, search, fortran

Given a 1D array

```
    A=(1,2,3,0,0,0,4,5,0,6,0)
```

I want to print a list of 1D arrays with same size, by searching non-zero element of `A`. From each non-zero element of `A`, I want the partial list of subsequent consecutive non-zero elements (padded with zeros at the end). In this case, the number of elements in `B` will be 3 (as there are exactly 3 pieces of non-zero sub-lists in `A`), and the expected result is:

```
    B1=(1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    B2=(4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    B3=(6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Could someone give me a suggestion on how to solve this? Then I can start coding it in Fortran.

Comment: @Gilles Since there are 6 nonzero elements in `A`,  I will extract from each nonzero element until meeting zero.

Comment: @Gilles  I deleted some arrays like `(2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`, since it can be calculated, and not simpley like that if the elements are not `1.0`.

Comment: Now that I understand the question I'm struggling to understand why you can't start writing your code.  Read the first element, if it's zero loop, if it's not zero write it into the first output array, then loop.  Read the second element, if it's zero remember to write the next non-zero value into the next output array, and so on and so forth.  What, really, are you waiting for ?  Get coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran requires that all variables are known at compile time, which means you cannot create an unknown amount of arrays.

However, the standard way to handle this type of problem is by using a two-dimensional array B instead.

```
implicit none
integer :: nsize,i,nsubarray,j,k
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: A
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: B
logical :: insubarray

    read(*,*) nsize !enter length of array A at the command line
    allocate(A(nsize))
    read(*,*) A !enter the array at the command line

    !first count the number of subarrays nsubarray we need
    nsubarray = 0
    insubarray = .False.
    do i = 1,nsize
        if (A(i).ne.0) then
            if (.not.insubarray) nsubarray = nsubarray + 1
            insubarray = .True.
        else
            insubarray = .False.
        end if
    end do

    !then allocate the appropriate 2D-array
    allocate(B(nsize,nsubarray))
    B = 0 !fill with zeros
    insubarray = .False.
    k = 1 !counts the "number" of subarray B_k
    j = 1 !counts the position inside B_k

    !now write the numbers into the correct subarrays
    do i = 1,nsize
        if (A(i).ne.0) then
            insubarray = .True.
            B(j,k) = A(i)
            j = j + 1
        else
            insubarray = .False.
        end if
        if (.not.insubarray) j = 1
        if (i.gt.1) then
            if ((A(i-1).ne.0).and.(A(i).eq.0)) then
                k = k + 1
            end if
        end if
    end do

    !finally write output in the required format:
    !this is obviously far more complex than it has to be, the expected arrays
    !are simply in B(:,1), B(:,2), B(:,3), ...
    do i = 1,nsubarray
        write(*,'(a1,i1,a2)', advance="no") 'B',i,'=('
        do j = 1,nsize
            if (j.lt.nsize) then
                write(*,'(i1,a1)', advance="no") B(j,i),','
            else
                write(*,'(i1)', advance="no") B(j,i)
            end if
        end do
        write(*,'(a1)') ')'
    end do
end
```

Another solution is of course to declare a large enough amount of (one-dimensional) arrays B_k and simply not use those that are no needed, but that would be sloppy and require a large amount of conditional statements.

Comment: *It is not possible to do exactly what you are asking for in Fortran* ???  Of course it is.  I presume (I haven't checked very closely) that this answer disproves its own first sentence.

Comment: Well I may be nitpicking the exact formulation of the question a bit, but if you read closely, the question asks how to "create a (presumably unknown) number of array [sic]", which is - at least to my knowledge - not possible. I explained why in my answer. It is obviously easily possible to solve the underlying problem in multiple ways, just not as the question (presumably) wants it to.

Comment: A 'list of 1D arrays' *is* a 2D array, so I agree with @HighPerformanceMark that your qualification is unnecessary.

Comment: I removed the mentioned section of my answer. There are still some fragments about the issue left though, because it is worth pointing out in my opinion. You may change this if you feel otherwise.